# driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities); in appium

Tags: appium

```
public class Mobiletest {
    private static AndroidDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException,
        InterruptedException {

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Redmi 1s");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.4");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        // capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage",
            "com.zipgo.customer");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity",
            "SplashActivity");
        capabilities.setCapability(
            MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT,
            "100");

        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),
            capabilities);
```

It shows below error as in Appium:

Multiple markers at this line

```
- AndroidDriver cannot be resolved to a type
- driver cannot be resolved to a variable
```

I have added gson jar and java client jar files also

Comment: Can you show more code? How are you defining `driver` variable?

Comment: above is the code

Comment: use AppiumDriver instead of Android Driver. It has to be "private static AppiumDriver driver;"

Answer (score 0):

You are probably adding wrong dependencies into your project.

In my case, these are the ones I'm using in my Appium lib:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'io.appium:java-client:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1'
    compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.21.0'
    compile 'com.testdroid:testdroid-api:2.9'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.21.0'
}
```

And then, when creating the AndroidDriver, I'm importing:

```
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobilePlatform;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to my example:

```
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "8d1737f5"); 
// Need your unique device name, search in google, only for real device
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "6.0.1");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "D://YourAPK.apk");
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage","com.sannacode.android.interviewtest");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.sannacode.android.interviewtest.MainActivity");
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: > error: Unhandled error: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\"C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\build-tools\19.1.0"\build-tools'
>     at Error (native)
>     at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:761:18)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

add Apache Commons Lang 3.8.1 for (Java 7+)
and Apache Commons Lang 2.6 (Requires Java 1.2 or later)

my java version is 8 and after adding Apache Commons Lang 3.8.1 solve my problem.